What would be the implications for society if AI completely took over artistic expression?
This is probably a confusing question but its the premise behind a short story I'm trying to write.
Basically in this world, humanity has developed specialized AI to such an extent that it can produce new media by itself faster than any human or company. From movies, to comic books, porn etc. It does everything, from brainstorming to post production, its all automated and run by large Media companies for their dedicated streaming platforms.
I'm curious what the societal impacts of this would be, despite the huge amount of content available today, there's always a handful of shows and movies that stand out every year. But what happens when those stand out movies/shows are being released daily?
The protagonist in my story is fed up with the constant blur of content generated by algorithms and escapes modern society into the rocky mountains to create her own original artwork in peace.
Would this be a somewhat common sentiment? Would people get bored of AI content despite its near perfect quality in favor of human created artwork, maybe even appreciating its inherent imperfections.

There is not 1 single society, and each individual reacts in different ways. There is no way to answer this in an objective way.

Hyper broad and unspecific questions that have: "What would be the implications for society..." really don't work  here as they require either narrowing down radically - or they elicit o/p answers.

There cannot be 365 "standout movies" per year, for the obvious reason that a "standout movie" has to stand out from the other movies released in that year. There can be 365 good movies released in a year, out of which a small number will stand out. P.S. Nothing which is entirely made by a machine can possibly be considered "artistic expression". It is mass-produced stuff, maybe high-quality mass-produced stuff, but artistic expression requires an artist expressing themself.

There's not one society as L.Dutch points out, nor is there a single set of biases inherent within programmers. Story-based and way too broad for an objective answer.

Anyone who can answer this is an oracle of our entire future. It’s not an answerable question: there are many answers, all novel length. Voting to close because clearly opinion based!

The real question for that society is the role of government to protect intellectual property. In the US, we have both copyright and patent protection. But that is being challenged by AI. Without government protection, there is no incentive to create new. That is a major social and economic issue.

Hi @ChellCPlus. It's worth helping you understand what's happened. This is a common question type on this Stack, but it's a type that's off-topic. We call it a high concept question. Stack Exchange has a fair number of rules and expectations and this question type runs afoul of a fair number of them, including the Book Rule (too broad), the necessity of being focused on a single, reasonably objective problem, avoiding questions that are too opinion-based, based too much on story circumstances or ... (*Continued*)

... personal/organization decisions/choices. There are others. Generally speaking, this type of question is asking for help writing the story (which is specifically off-topic per the [help/on-topic]) rather than building the world, which is a framework or infrastructure independent of all stories upon which stories are written. May I suggest that you consider using our Sandbox for proposed questions? It's not a place to get the question you want to ask answered. ... (*Continued*)

... Rather, it's a place where you can get help asking the question in the right way so that it has a lower (ideally no) chance of being closed. Cheers.

@ChellCPlus: Hi! Your question got closed recently. I am willing to help you to rephrase your question to make it "fit" for the requirements on WB:SE. I need to know: Do you feel you got everything you wanted already (at least enough for your next step) or do you feel you was misunderstood and would like to give it another go?

It would be not that much different from what we have now. There already is so much artistic output being produced that we just can't consume all of it. This creates some predictable economic incentives:
-- the oversupply of art causes the price of art to plummet;
-- the plummeting price of art causes the artists' marginal profits to shrink;
-- the professional artists try to protect their livelihood by grabbing an ever greater share of the market. A whole system of agents, promotors, critics etc. develops to facilitate this (and to skim some of the money for themselves in the process): we call it a 'music industry', a 'film industry', a 'book industry' etc., which are essentially different branches of the same system for each of the artistic mediums.
-- being a beginner artist with no connections within the industry no longer pays the bills, so fewer people become professional artists. There is also less incentive for people to become amateur artists: the cost of becoming competent for your own enjoyment is too great compared to the cost of just buying ready-made art;
-- the art industry consolidates into an oligopoly. The art itself becomes uniform as local/non-mainstream art forms cannot sustain themselves economically and are abandoned by the art industry and may even be actively undermined by it. Professional artistic experimantation becomes an equivalent of a startup, and is perceived by the art industry as a low-investment, high-risk, high-reward proposition, given a small amount of money to try their best and left to fend for itself.
If AI did make artistic expression cheaper still, the same dynamic would still apply, just a bit more so than today.
As for your protagonist, he would be one of the few. Remember, you can only expect making art outside of this system to be a money-losing proposition. How will he make a living out in the Rockies? What sort of compromises would he need to make in order to be able to create art? What additional compromises would he need to make if he wants to then share his art with the world dominated by art industry that does not like independent competitors? Any potential lone wolf artist would need to find an answer to these and many other questions, and finding an answer to most of the questions is unlikely to be enough.
As for the society, it will keep buying the AI content. The art industry will ensure that this content is cheap and easily accessible, and that alternatives are expensive and difficult to access. Most consumers (i.e. people) are not after the best product but after a good enough one, and if AI art is indeed good enough, they will have no reason to complain. Human-made art will not disappear, but the art industry dominated by AI-generated content will have every reason to denigrate it: expect it to be called elitist, snobbish, backward and generally uncool, and probably linked to the far right too. (By the way, how would your protagonist, isolated in the Rockies as he is, cope with accusations of holding politically incorrect views? These are common in any industry where your profits depend on social approval.)

And as soon as that lone artist generates something novel, the system will copy it, create new versions of it, and sell it for very cheap. When governments do not protect the value of intellectual property, people stop inventing new art, new inventions, new science.

@DavidR, protection of intellectual property is a rather recent thing. Despite that we human have been inventing things for quite some time, I would say

@DavidR, thank you. That's assuming that the human-made art can be converted into a cheap AI-made copy. That's generally not true of any art performed collectively: AI is great at observing but if the viewer has to do something as part of the act, then AI will not help you with that. Or you could have art venues hidden from the AI as much as possible; then it will not be able to replicate the art due to being unable to observe it to begin with.

@L.Dutch There are always those who invent, but fewer do so with no benefits. While the effects of no protection of the cotton gin are known, now we are seeing the effects of too much protection, for example software patents and genetic patents. Thus, the arguments today need more nuance.

It would just be another form of art, novelty value for a while. There's too much vested money in traditional Western art & artists.
For most of the World it wouldn't have much impact. And even for the West if you're not interested in a streaming company, you won't see it.

And wouldn't be sustainable by itself anyway, unless you had very different AI than we do now that works very differently, we've already seen that, with only itself to 'feed' and train on it very rapidly becomes not art at all, you sooner or later get nothing but 'noise' or 'mess' no one will pay for so it can't plausibly replace our art yet and can only exist as an adjunct to it, and I've not seen any suggestion anyone even has an inkling how to make that not so yet.
